# In Lightning is there Inline-Editing like we know it from the Aloha-UI or VF pages?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, inlineeditsupport, ui

Our clients are using inline-edit quite heavily, it saves a lot of time and feels also way better than pressing "Edit" to get in the full edit mode all the time.

Is there a similar functionality existing or planned also for Lightning?

If not, I would advocate to provide a functionality like that again - at least for desktop usage. But also for mobile scenarios it would be very handy (of course the current Aloha hover-pencil-display and invocation method "double-click" is not good enough for mobile cases).

To always have to switch a record between full *view-* and *edit-mode* even if you e. g. just want to fix a typo in one certain field is less comfortable. Also in SPAs it leads to updates of huge parts of the UI, possible scrolling position got lost in long tapestries and you might get a disruptive feeling. So I am sure: inline editing was great and would be great in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question yesterday on a Salesforce event and this seems to be the current status:

**There is no Inline-Editing support in current version of the Salesforce1 mobile app.** It has been discussed but Salesforce decided against having this functionality for the mobile app at least for now.

They plan also to provide a desktop app based on Lightning. For that it is yet not decided if it will provide Inline-Editing or not.

Further updates and more information on the roadmap for Inline-Editing is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring '16 release, this is now available:

[Edit Inline in Lightning Experience"](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_general_inline_editing.htm)

Comment: The link is broken.