# Clicking Lightning Button calling visualforcePage

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Clicking on Lightning button,I have to call visual force page dynamically based on record Id..how to do that ...onclick of button how to pass the perticular employee Id?

```
      <aura:component controller="AlloactionController" implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="isdisplay" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="emplst" type="Employee__c[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<table  class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
    <th class="head"> employee Id</th>
    <th class="head"> FBP allocation</th>
    <th class="head">TotalFBPallocation</th>
    <aura:iteration items="{!emplst}" var="employee"/>
    <tr>
        <td  class="cell">
            <ui:inputText Value="{!v.employee.Id}"/>
        </td>
        <td  class="cell">
            <ui:inputText Value="{!v.employee.FBP_Allocation_Limit_per_Year__c}"/></td>
        <td  class="cell"><ui:inputText Value="{!v.employee.Total_FBP_Allocations_This_Year__c }"/></td>
        <td  class="cell"> <lightning:button label="FBP Allocation" onclick="{!c.VfpageCall}" id="{!employee.Id}" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
({
doInit:function(component,event,helper){
    alert('@@@calling @@@');
    var action=component.get("c.fbpallocationDetails");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.emplst",response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
 VfpageCall : function(component, event, helper) {
    var myId = 'a0O6F00000mZKTW'; /

    var vfUrl = 'https://empowerhrms-dev-ed--c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/FBPallocation?Id='+myId;
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": vfUrl
    });
    urlEvent.fire();

}
```

})

***//
  I want ID DYNAMICALLY dynamically based on fbp alloaction button click

### //suppose 5rows are there ..user clicked on 3rd row.I want that Id in javascript side [3rd row id]***

```
 public class AlloactionController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Employee__c> fbpallocationDetails(){
    List<Employee__c> employeList=new  List<Employee__c>();
    employeList=[select id,FBP_Allocation_Limit_per_Year__c,Total_FBP_Allocations_This_Year__c from Employee__c];
    system.debug('employeelist================>'+ employeList);
    return employeList;
}
```

}

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98962/unable-to-redirect-to-a-vf-page-or-external-page-using-lightning-component-in-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `{!employee.Id}` in your name attribute instead of id of lightning:button.

```
<lightning:button label="FBP Allocation" onclick="{!c.VfpageCall}" name="{!employee.Id}" />
```

Get the Id in your VfPageCall function,

```
var myId = event.getSource().get('v.name');
```

If you are using the component inside `one/one.app`, you can use this:

```
        var vfUrl = 'https://myinstance.visual.force.com/apex/MyVFPage?Id='+myId;
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": vfUrl
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
```

Or if you are using the component any other place where `one/one.app` is not available, you can use this:

```
window.parent.location =vfUrl;
```

Comment: Thank you..but How can I open visual force page based on Id ..please check above code

Comment: Updated my answer. You can concatenate your Id with the URL.

Comment: Thank you ..you are right..how to pass Id dynamically can  you please tell me..var myID what are you doing I want that value dynamically

Comment: Please check my updated code

Comment: Oh dear! You have to fetch the Id from the variable/attribute where you have kept it. I have updated my code assuming you have a attribute to store the Id or you want to fetch from the List. We expect you would use your intelligence on whatever help we provide.

Comment: yes dear..I understand but here iam getting so many Ids right..so I confused..that why I posted that question and updated the code.

Comment: Thank you for telling the specific requirement. I have updated the code, hope it will help.

Comment: Glad I helped. Be specific about your issue, that helps! :)

Comment: any idea about how it will work in community as i don't want to hardcode url to it