# Problem with iframe for visualforce page in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, iframe

I am embedding a Visualforce page from a managed package into a Lightning Component using an iFrame. This is throwing an XSS error when a community user attempts to access the page.

I have replaced the actual domain name with clientdomain for customer confidentiality.

> Refused to display 'https://clientdomain--flex.cs82.my.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisual…land--flex--b25.cs82.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252Fb25__lightning_calendar' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

In the Lightning component I have got the URL hardcoded as

```
https://clientdomain--flex--b25.cs82.visual.force.com/apex/lightning_calendar"
```

The community users are logging into a site with the domain as

> https://flex-clientdomain.cs82.force.com

If I can replace the hardcoding of the domain in the Lightning component I suspect this may fix the problem as the user is not authenticated to SF on that domain, but when I have tried using a string like

```
/visual.force.com/apex/lightning_calendar
```

or

```
/apex/lightning_calendar
```

It throws an error with Invalid page where the component is embedded in a community page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the answer to this as well and i found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97429/how-to-use-a-visualforce-page-as-a-component-lightning-community-page/).  For your code you would have to do

```
<iframe src="../apex/lightning_calendar" ></iframe>
```

instead of

```
<iframe src="/apex/lightning_calendar" ></iframe>
```

it is an odd work around